# character reading in a variety way

Tags: python, io

I have a text file in this format:

```
abc? cdfde" nhj.cde' dfwe-df$sde.....
```

How can i ignore all the special characters, blanks, numbers, end of the lines, etc and write only the characters in another file?For example, the above file becomes

```
abccdfdenhjcdedfwedfsde.....
```

And from this output file,

- Should able to read single character by character till the end of file.
- Should be able to read two characters at a time, like ab,bc,cc,cd,df,... from above file
- Should be able to read three characters at a time, like abc,bcc,ccd,cdf,... from the above file

First of all, how can i read only characters and write to external file?
I can read single character by character by using f.read(1) till end of file.How can i apply this to read 2,3 chars at a time, that too skipping only one character(that is, if i have abcd, i should read ab,bc,cd but not ab,cd(this, i think can be done by f.read(2))). Thanks. I am doing this for cryptanalysis work to analyze ciphertexts by frequency.

Comment: There is nothing specific to cryptography in this question, nor is there anything specific to any version of Python. The mechanics of doing what you ask are quite straightforward. Work through *any* Python tutorial, and you should be able to do this for yourself after about 30 minutes.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire, why so hostile to someone who is obviously newish to StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to peek ahead (read a few extra characters at a time), you need a buffered file object. The following class does just that:

```
import io

class AlphaPeekReader(io.BufferedReader):
    def readalpha(self, count):
        "Read one character, and peek ahead (count - 1) *extra* characters"
        val = [self.read1(1)]

        # Find first alpha character
        while not val[0].isalpha():
            if val == ['']:
                return ''  # EOF
            val = [self.read1(1)]


        require = count - len(val)
        peek = self.peek(require * 3)  # Account for a lot of garbage
        if peek == '':  # EOF
               return val[0]

        for c in peek:
            if c.isalpha():
               require -= 1
               val.append(c)
               if not require:
                   break

        # There is a chance here that there were not 'require' alpha chars in peek
        # Return anyway.
        return ''.join(val)
```

This *attempts* to find extra characters beyond the one character you are reading, but doesn't make a guarantee it'll be able to satisfy your requirements. It could read fewer if we are at the end of the file or if there is a lot of non-alphabetic text in the next block.

Usage:

```
with AlphaPeekReader(io.open(filename, 'rb')) as alphafile:
    alphafile.readalpha(3)
```

Demo, using a file with your example input:

```
>>> f = io.open('/tmp/test.txt', 'rb')
>>> alphafile = AlphaPeekReader(f)
>>> alphafile.readalpha(3)
'abc'
>>> alphafile.readalpha(3)
'bcc'
>>> alphafile.readalpha(3)
'ccd'
>>> alphafile.readalpha(10)
'cdfdenhjcd'
>>> alphafile.readalpha(10)
'dfdenhjcde'
```

To use the `readalpha()` calls in a loop, where you get each and every character separately plus the two next 2 bytes, use the [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) with a sentinel:

```
for alpha_with_extra in iter(lambda: alphafile.readalpha(3), ''):
    # Do something with alpha_with_extra
```

Comment: Isn't this form of string concatenation extremely inefficient? Why not turn `readalpha()` into a generator and then use `''.join()` on it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: probably, updated a little. This probably would also benefit from a proper class and buffered reads.

Comment: @Martin there is a slight mistake in your program. If there is a string abcd, if i do alphafile.readalpha(2), i will get ab,cd as answer, What i actually needed is ab,bc,cd

Comment: @JustinCarrey: Ah, you needed a peek? Updating.

Comment: @JustinCarrey: updated my answer. If you need a guaranteed 3 bytes each time you'll need to go to slower methods or something that reads progressively larger strings using `.peek()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters instead of typing a command alphafile.readalpha(3) everytime, how can i run it in the loop so that all the strings of length 3 are displayed one by one?

Comment: @JustinCarrey: use `iter(callable, sentinel)`; I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To read a line from a file:

```
import fileinput

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
for line in fileinput.input("sample.txt"):
    outstring = ''.join(ch for ch in line if ch.isalpha())
    text_file.write("%s"%outstring)

text_file.close()
```

Comment: should also ignore line breaks. so, should not read line by line. output text is one single line long concatenation of all the characters

Comment: In this example, I did not add a line break in the output (if you want a line break in output, you must write "%s\n"): the result is a long line.

Comment: Did you try this? Just because it reads line by line does not mean it will write separate lines.

Comment: if, for any reason, you do not want to loop over the input file, do: f=open("sample.txt") data=f.read outstring=''.join(ch for ch in data if ch.isalpha())